# Is there a module that displays a field only when a condition is met?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I am looking a module that will only display some fields if a condition is met. Basically only administrators or editors should be able to see those fields in the display. In editing mode it should be alright as only editors have the right to view those fields.

I have checked the documenation for  Conditional Fields module and Field Conditional States which enable this but they do it based on field contents, but I want run if a PHP condition is met. Are there any other similar modules which implement this?

Comment: Hi you can also do it without a module? is there any specific reason why you require module.

Comment: @DEVARAJJOHNSON I hve settled on the Field Permissions module, but can you explain how it would be done without a module?

Comment: yes, in form_alter use $form['field_name']['#access'] = FALSE;  will hide the field in the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Field permissions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions). It allows for role-based conditional display.